# Add function name to decorator output

Tags: python, function, decorator, python-decorators

I have a python code snippet that allows me to time function as a decorator. I would like to add function name to the output. and time in milli-seconds

```
def func_timer(func):
    def f(*args, **kwargs):
        start   = time.time()
        results = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print "Elapsed: %.6fs" % (time.time() - start)
        return results

    return f
```

Usage is:

```
@func_timer
def foo():
    pass
```

Current Output is :

```
Elapsed: 0.005168s
```

Output desired:

```
foo Elapsed: 5.168ms
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function objects have a `__name__` attribute, you can use that. Simply multiply the time by 1000 if you want milliseconds:

```
print "%s Elapsed: %.6fms" % (func.__name__, (time.time() - start) * 1000)
```